# Getting specific chunk of data from file on FTP server

Tags: c, ftp, ftp-client

I am writing FTP client in C. I am not making any changes to Server program.
I want to get specific amount of data from a file on server.
Suppose I have a file on server and I want to read last 100 bytes from the file. I don't want to read whole file.

I am able to get whole file using 
**RETR filename** but I didn't  find any way to read specific amount of bytes.

Is there any way to do this for a standard FTP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this for a standard FTP server?

No. You can tell the server the position where it should start with the `REST` (restart) command, but you cannot tell it how much data it should send. All you can do is close the data channel after you've received the amount of data you want. The FTP server will probably complain about this because it received a RST (writing against a closed socket) but in most cases this should not cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll do some research on **REST**. I am trying to write a multithreaded client. Is this the right way to do it??

Comment: You mean a multithreaded client, where each thread gets a different chunk? I think this makes only sense for very large files because each thread has the overhead of a full client (e.g. connection setup, login, create data channel...). Also, lots of servers restrict the number of connections from the same IP address.

Comment: Yes yes :) I understand that. I am just implementing it for learning purpose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's [proposal for `RANG` command](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-bryan-ftp-range-08), just in case the server supports it as an experimental feature.